# python how to extract repeated string by regular expression

Tags: python

i have a database

```
database=['3456734567','qqqqgtcgagagagctacgagaqqqqgtcgagagagctacgagaqqqqgtcgagagagctacgaga']
```

and I want to extract the repeated string as
'34567'
'qqqqgtcgagagagctacgaga'

therefore I use the code as followings:

```
def string(s):
    return re.search(r'(.+?)\1+', s).group(1)

print string(data[0]) 
print string(data[1])
```

however it only output '34567' and 'q'

please tell me how to edit and then get the result 'qqqqgtcgagagagctacgaga'

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, you can use a greedy operator instead of a non-greedy one:

```
r'(.+)\1+'
```

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> The `*`, `+`, and `?` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against `<H1>title</H1>`, it will match the entire string, and not just ''. Adding `?` after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using `.*?` in the previous expression will match only `<H1>`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the '?' in your group, it makes the + qualifier eager, but you want a greedy one that matches as many repetitions as possible.

```
In [1]: re.match(r'(.+)\1+', 
         'qqqqgtcgagagagctacgagaqqqqgtcgagagagctacgagaqqqqgtcgagagagctacgaga').groups()
Out[1]: ('qqqqgtcgagagagctacgaga',)
```

Comment: you know `{1,}` is the same as `+`?

Comment: Indeed, I'll change the answer to highlight it's ommitting ? afer the first + that makes the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The below expression should give you the required result:

```
def string(s):
return re.search(r'(.+)\1+', s).group(1)

>>> print string(database[0])
34567

print string(database[1])
qqqqgtcgagagagctacgaga
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `.group()` will only return the parentheses-wrapped part of the expression. You can use `.start()` and `.end()` to get the indices of the original string where the match happened:

```
def string(s):
    match = re.search(r'(.+?)\1+', s)
    return s[match.start() : match.end()] if match is not None else None
```

Comment: When running your example with the OP data I get  `qqqq` and `3456734567`

Comment: `if match is not None` is the same as `if match`

Comment: `.group(0)` gives you the entire match